# How to start with Quartz scheduler in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, quartz-scheduler

I need to work with **Quartz scheduler** in my MVC3 project. The requirements are schedule the task based on my database values. Say like, Sending an email to the specific person when the time period reaches. Is there any good article or tutorial on how to start with **Quartz scheduler** in MVC3.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the tutorial?

http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/index.html

Make sure that you don't run Quartz inside IIS worker process - it's better to have a windows service as it won't be recycled at unexpected times like worker process.

Comment: I looked before. Its like intermediate and not convenient for me. Is there any step by step tutorial available for Quartz MVC3.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following may be of help to you

[Using Quartz.NET, Spring.NET and NHibernate to run Scheduled Tasks in ASP.NET](http://www.zorched.net/2009/03/07/using-quartznet-springnet-and-nhibernate-to-run-scheduled-tasks-in-aspnet/)

[Cron Maker](http://www.cronmaker.com/)

To fully get to understand the tutorial, I would recommend you download the source code and go through the test cases and after that the tutorials will make sense.